# Nohup is not writing log to output file

Tags: python, nohup

I am using the following command to run a python script in the background:

```
nohup ./cmd.py > cmd.log &
```

But it appears that nohup is not writing anything to the log file. cmd.log is created but is always empty. In the python script, I am using `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print` to print to standard output. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Which variant of `nohup` are you using?  The BSD version writes to a file called `nohup.out` in the current directory (or `$HOME/nohup.out` if the current directory isn't writable).  I don't see a way to change the output file name...

Comment: @wulong That's only if if stdout is a terminal.

Comment: I also tried the command without redirection and it didn't create the nohup.out file at all. I don't know which variant it is but I am on SunOS 5.10 if that helps.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

It looks like you need to flush stdout periodically (e.g. `sys.stdout.flush()`). In my testing Python doesn't automatically do this even with `print` until the program exits.

Comment: python as well as other C stdio-based programs uses line-buffering in interactive case (stdout is connected to a tty) and block-buffering when redirected to a file. If `python -u` doesn't work; `nohup` might have introduced its own buffering.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian As of today, `nohup` doesn't buffer output and `python -u` works just fine. (just an update for people)

Comment: @Pius: [`nohup` is a POSIX utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nohup.html) there could be different implementations on different platforms. btw, python3 I/O is no longer C stdio-based but it has similar buffering behavior.

Comment: @jfs stderr buffering behavior changed in Python 3.9, it is now always line-buffered. See [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue13601).

Answer (score 523):

You can run Python with the `-u` flag to avoid output buffering:

```
nohup python -u ./cmd.py > cmd.log &
```

Comment: @kommradHomer I guess it depends on the amount of output on stdout/stderr your program produces.

Comment: Warning: it [doesn't always work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34753765/1422096). I don't know why. Do you?

Answer (score 77):

- Using `-u`  with `nohup` worked for me. Using `-u` will force the `stdout`, `stderr` streams to be unbuffered. It will not affect stdin. Everything will be saved in "***nohup.out*** " file. Like this-

  ```sh
  nohup python -u your_code.py &
  ```

  You can also save it into your directory. This way-

  ```sh
  nohup python -u your_code.py > your_directory/nohup.out &
  ```
- Also, you can use `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`. If you set it to a non-empty string it will work same as the `-u` option. For using this run below commands before running python code.

  ```sh
  export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
  ```

  or

  ```sh
  export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
  ```

**P.S.-** *I will suggest using tools like cron-job to run things in the background and scheduled execution.*

Comment: What's the difference with the answer from @vz0?

Comment: @Deqing there is no difference.

Answer (score 21):

```
export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
nohup ./cmd.py > cmd.log &
```

or

```
nohup python -u ./cmd.py > cmd.log &
```

https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u

Answer (score 5):

Python 3.3 and above has a flush argument to print and this is the only method that worked for me.

```
print("number to train = " + str(num_train), flush=True)
print("Using {} evaluation batches".format(num_evals), flush=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but not connected with a Python process. I was running a script which did a nohup and the script ran periodically via cron.

I was able to resolve the problem by:

1. redirecting the stdin , stdout and stderr
2. ensuring the the script being invoked via nohup didn't run anything else in the background

PS: my scripts were written in ksh running on RHEL

Answer (score -1):

I run my scripts in the following way and I have no problem at all:

```
nohup python my_script.py &> my_script.out &
```

comparing with your syntax looks like you are only missing a "&" symbol after your input...

Comment: how did you find this workaround?