# nohup process doesn't keep running in background when used in python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, background-process, mysql-python, nohup

I want to run below mysql query on remote server in background.

> nohup mysql -h10.0.100.1 -P3306 -utest -ppassword -Dcms -e "select * from table1 ;" & echo $!

When above command is execute manually from command line, I see process is running in background (table has records which would return response over 2 mins)

> [root@TEST_Server]# ps -ef | grep mysql
>   root     11144  9227 19 17:44 pts/0    00:00:01 mysql -h 10.0.100.1 -P 3306 -utest -px xxxxxxx -Dcms -e select * from table1 ;

However when I use this code in python script, I don't see any process running in background. It is not executing intended mysql command
Python code snippet:

```
 cmd = "nohup mysql -h10.0.100.1 -P3306 -uroot -ppassword -Dcms \
            -e \"select * from table1 ;\" & echo $!"  
 out, err, code = ssh_client.execute_sudo_command(["%s" % cmd])  
 print out
```

It returns the PID however I don't see that process is not really running in background for period of time it intended to run.

I have tried solution mentioned in https://github.com/brooklyncentral/brooklyn/issues/162 or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

> ssh localhost 'nohup mysqld > out 2> err < /dev/null & echo $! > pid.txt ; exit 0'

but it didn't worked out.

I am using python 2.7.6 and SSHClient for remote connection.
Any suggestions to overcome this issue?

Comment: This is not an answer, but this may save you a lot of time: http://www.fabfile.org/

Comment: Thanks @ReutSharabani, will surely take a look at this as an alternative

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919980/nohup-is-not-writing-log-to-output-file maybe that can help you