# How to redirect prints to log file on nohup

Tags: python

```
nohup python3 main.py > log.output &
```

So with this, I am getting some output by my framework but my individual `print` statements are not being logged to `log.output`.  Is there anyway to fix this?

Output under nohup

`nohup: ignoring input
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 571-306-491
XXX - - [28/Jan/2018 17:56:42] "POST /TestEndpoint HTTP/1.1" 201 -
XXX - - [28/Jan/2018 17:57:00] "POST /TestEndpoint HTTP/1.1" 201 -`

Normal running output

```
python3 main.py
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with stat
* Debugger is active!
* Debugger PIN: 571-306-491
test endpoint
XXX - - [28/Jan/2018 18:01:52] "POST /TestEndpoint HTTP/1.1" 201 -
```

Tried all of these :

```
nohup python3 -u main.py &
nohup python3 main.py > log.output 2>&1 &
nohup python3 -u main.py > log.output 2>&1 &
nohup python3 main.py > log.output &
nohup python3 -u main.py > log.output &
```

only this shows the correct output  `python3 main.py`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nohup is not writing log to output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919980/nohup-is-not-writing-log-to-output-file)

Comment: @venky__ I tried every solution in there, none of them cause my print to my displayed

Answer (score 0):

`print` by default sends data to sys.stdout, but its buffered unless you explicitly stated otherwise.

Could try redirecting `stderr` in `stdout` also, just to check if nohup affects it in some way.

`nohup python3 main.py > log.output 2>&1 &`

Comment: Still not getting print statements, there should be a print statement between every POST, they are not showing up.  They show up just fine if I run this in the foreground without using nohup / & .. I edited main post to show log output

Comment: maybe there is ```nohup.out``` file that all printed lines get redirected to, and is located in the same folder where you were when you run this command

Comment: I tried that as well `nohup python3 -u main.py &` puts the output to nohup.out and that does not contain prints either

Comment: how about calling ```print``` with ```print('...', flush=True)?```

Comment: Thanks works ... but I have tons of prints.  Is there not a better solution then adding `flush=True` to every print statement?

Comment: ```flush``` flag is added in Python 3.3. Before that you had to call ```sys.stdout.flush```. Not sure if that is convenient too, but you could call if in certain points in code. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/230774/3029287