# reticulate doesn't print to console in real time

Tags: python, r, reticulate, console-output

Using Python's `print()` (or to the best of my knowledge, any other console output generating) function in loop structures and running the code via **reticulate** in R, the output is only printed after the execution finished. For example, take the following loop which goes to sleep for 1.5 seconds after each iteration; the run numbers are all printed in one go after the loop is through. The same applies when saving the Python code to a separate .py file and then running `reticulate::py_run_file()`.

```r
library(reticulate)

py_run_string("
import time

for i in range(5):
   print(str(i))
   time.sleep(1.5) # sleep for 1.5 sec
")
```

Does anyone know where this behavior comes from and, if possible, how to circumvent it?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with python. When you put that into a script and run it using `nohup thisscript.py` you can see that the output will be be held back until the script finishes. That's just from my experience. Unfortunately, I have no idea why

Comment: Amazing, inserting `sys.stdout.flush()` right after the `print()` call indeed sends a status update to the console at each iteration. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, you need to force pyhton to export the standard output at times. You can do this by adding `sys.stdout.flush()` to your code:

```
library(reticulate)

py_run_string("
import time
import sys

for i in range(5):
   print(str(i))
   time.sleep(1.5) # sleep for 1.5 sec
   sys.stdout.flush()
")
```

[see over here described with nohup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12920094/3250126)

Answer (score 7):

For future reference, enforcing to flush the stream via `print(..., flush = True)` works as well (as suggested [here](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate)) and renders importing **sys** obsolete:

```r
library(reticulate)

py_run_string("
import time

for i in range(5):
   print(str(i), flush = True)
   time.sleep(1.5)
")
```