# Run python script in background on server and get script output

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell

So, I need to run a python script on a server but ***I want the script to output whatever it outputs into a file so I can check what it done after it finished.*** However I also need the script to continue running if the ssh tunnel to the server gets interrupted or closed. Here is what I know:

`python3 run.py >> out.txt`
will output correctly.

`nohup python3 run.py`
will output correctly and be safe from interruption. it will also output into a nohup.out but will not run in the background of the current session (thus blocking me from doing anything else).

So I would think

`nohup python3 run.py >> out.txt &`
would work for me but it does not.
I've tried different combinations of what I want but just cannot get it to work... 
once I add `&` it appears the output to the files just stops going. I have no clue why though.
any help appreciated!

Comment: You are probably experiencing this buffering issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919980/nohup-is-not-writing-log-to-output-file

Comment: @VPfB aha! thank you that seemed to be the problem! interesting issue but glad its solved.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. The moderators will now almost certainly close this as a duplicate. Anyway, welcome to SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nohup is not writing log to output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919980/nohup-is-not-writing-log-to-output-file)

Answer (score 1):

Just look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/513496/how-can-i-run-a-command-from-the-terminal-without-blocking-it):

```
python3 yourscript.py >> out.txt & disown
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30011751)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is been already answered here

https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

You need to use `tmux` to keep it running in background

Comment: Thats not exactly what I asked though. I can get it running after ending the ssh session its the output of my script that is the problem,

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to run your command in the background with `&`. Then just write:

```
disown -a
```

Comment: thing is is that once I use ```&``` the script no longer outputs anything into the file

Answer (score 0):

for anyone experiencing similar issues there is problem with nohup and python output buffering I guess.
see: [Nohup is not writing log to output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919980/nohup-is-not-writing-log-to-output-file).

but the fix is:

`nohup python3 -u run.py >> out.txt &`

(Answer provided by @VPfB)