# Bash won't redirect output to a file and run in the background

Tags: python, bash, stdout

I've seen many similar questions to this, but the problem is that none of the other solutions have fixed my issue.  I want to run 2 python scripts and redirect their output to separate log files using `nohup`.

This code is located in a bash script called `startmain`:

```
nohup python3 GUI.py > GUI.log 2>&1 &
nohup python3 main.py > main.log 2>&1 &
```

When I run `sh startmain`, the **scripts both execute, but nothing is written to either log file.**

Now let's say instead I change the `startmain` code by removing the `&` characters at the end of the line:

```
nohup python3 GUI.py > GUI.log 2>&1
nohup python3 main.py > main.log 2>&1
```

This code says I don't want the scripts running in the background, so only GUI.py runs; **however, here it actually directs all the output from GUI.py to GUI.log**. I know why main.py doesn't run here, but I don't know why the output is written to GUI.log in this case but not when I try and run the scripts in the background.

Any idea what my issue is here? What sets my question apart from the similar ones is that I'm executing 2 scripts, which could be a reason why it's not working.

Comment: What about `nohup python3 -u GUI.py > GUI.log 2>&1 &`?

Comment: @KamilCuk that worked! I see here what the `-u` option does: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/5nvaic/what_does_python_u_do_and_what_is_an_unbuffered/  but why did that fix the problem?

Comment: `why did that fix the problem?` Well, the output was buffered inside `python` so it didn't output until a specified count (like 4 kilobytes) were written. So you "didn't wait long enough". With `-u` they are written as they go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @KamilCuk for the help!

Adding a `-u` option fixed the issue:

```
nohup python3 -u GUI.py > GUI.log 2>&1
nohup python3 -u main.py > main.log 2>&1
```

*But why did this work?*

Because by default, the stdout/stderr output is buffered, and only gets flushed at specific intervals (e.g. every 1kB). The "-u" option eliminates the buffer with python and will write the output immediately to the destination.

**NOTE**: this question is actually a duplicate of [nohup-is-not-writing-log-to-output-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919980/nohup-is-not-writing-log-to-output-file)