# nohup not writing to nohup.out on CodeDeploy

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-code-deploy, nohup

I have a Spring Boot Java20 application that I have set up to run on a Linux server using AWS CodeDeploy. Everything works as expected, except when CodeDeploy runs the following command from the `deploy.sh`:

```
nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=uat target/pow-wow-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar &
```

**Problem**

It does not create an expected `nohup.out` file.

When I run the `deploy.sh` manually it does create the `nohup.out` file.

**Question**

How do I get the `deploy.sh` to create the `nohup.out` file?

**More Info**

When CodeDeploy executes the `deploy.sh` it does so using the `root` user.  When I run it manually, I use my own user.

**deploy.sh**

```
echo "about to deploy to pow-wow ($USER) ..."
export JAVA_HOME=/home/jboss/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
echo $JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
cd /home/jboss/bitbucket/pow-wow
pwd
echo "stopping pow-wow ..."
echo | lsof -t -i tcp:8080
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i tcp:8080)
mv pow-wow-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar target/
echo "Sorting logs  ..."
cd /home/jboss/bitbucket/pow-wow/logs
pwd
if [ -e nohup.out ]
then
  cat nohup.out >> nohup-$(date --iso).out
  echo "archive logs to nohup-date.out and remove nohup.out"
  rm nohup.out
else
  echo "could not find /home/jboss/bitbucket/pow-wow/logs/nohup.out"
  ls
fi
echo "starting pow-wow ..."
cd /home/jboss/bitbucket/pow-wow
nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=uat target/pow-wow-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar &
if [ -e nohup.out ]
then
  mv nohup.out logs/
  echo "Created /home/jboss/bitbucket/pow-wow/logs/nohup.out"
else
  echo "Could not find nohup.out that should have been created from nohup java -jar"
  pwd
  ls
fi
echo "Run Start pow-wow."
```

**Output**

```
[stdout]Could not find nohup.out that should have been created from nohup java -jar
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you *assuming* the file isn't created because it prints that message or is the file not actually there? Because in the former case I would try to add a delay before checking whether the file exists.

Comment: Hi Federico, the `nohup.out` never gets added. Even if I go look after the process has run, it does not exist.

Comment: I have tried adding `-u` parameter, but it just got an error saying it's an invalid parameter.  i.e. `nohup java -u -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=uat target/pow-wow-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar &`.  People were suggesting that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919980/nohup-is-not-writing-log-to-output-file.

Comment: That's a python option, not a `nohup` one. So you're passing it to java. It may be a problem with writing permissions in the current directory. Check whether it created `nohup.out` inside the user's home directory instead. As a last ditch effort, try `nohup java -u -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=uat target/pow-wow-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar > nohup.out &`.

Comment: CodeDeploy executes its own process, and is logging to its own deployment, e.g. /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/xxxx/yyyy/logs/scripts.log. However, the `deploy.sh` is starting the application, so I would have thought it would output the logs.

Comment: Thanks, adding `> nohup.out` did create the file: `root  root      0 Aug 24 10:33 nohup.out`.  However, it is empty.

Comment: I think the logs cannot be outputted to `nohup.out`. I am going to find a solution using Couldwatch: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-cloudwatch-agent.html

Comment: Hi @ Federico klez Culloca, I was wring, the `> nohup.out` works, it is now writing to the file.  You did answer my question, thank you.

Comment: Why not just modify java logging to log to a file instead of the console?